# Tool to test TCP errors

Tags: linux, networking

Anyone know of a tool to test tcp connections in linux.. I'm looking for something to tell me if it experienced a dropped packet or such

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tcpdump serves this purpose. http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html

Answer (score 2):

tcptrack - Monitor TCP connections on the network

http://linux.die.net/man/1/tcptrack

Answer (score -1):

Server:

Open a tcp port with netcat so for example to open port 80 tcp I would use:

nc -l 80

Client:

Check the tcp port with telnet so to connect to port 80:

telnet destination_ip 80